# sshfs problem when losing connection

Tags: sshfs

I've a problem when I lost the wireless network connection after mounting a remote folder with sshfs on Linux. When I lost the connection the shell become frozen, if I open another shell and I try to access to the mounting point also this new shell froze. Is there a workaround?

Comment: See here for the best answer I found about this https://serverfault.com/questions/6709/sshfs-mount-that-survives-disconnect/#639735

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you attempt to access an SSHFS filesystem where the underlying connection has gone away your requests will hang because the system cannot reach the remote machine to complete the request.

If you are mounting the filesystem with `-o reconnect` (See the `sshfs` man page) the system should reconnect on its own.  If it does not the only workaround I'm aware of is to force-unmount and remount the filesystem.