# Remote encrypted mount

Tags: backup, mount, remote-access, ssh-keys

I tried this [sshfs without shell access](https://serverfault.com/questions/904234/sshfs-without-shell-access), but I realized I should ask opposite way

I would love to mount remote file system automatically, over encrypted tunnel preferably using private/public keys.

It should not mean any security risk (no ssh login or so), only reading/writing to remote sub-folder (like NFS over openVpn / unlike sshfs)

It should preserve user, groups, permissions

It should be easy to configure (like sshfs / unlike NFS overVpn)

It should be in standard repositories (linux)

It should reconnect if connection drops (or ip change)

Is there such thing or am I asking too much ?

Comment: You are asking too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On remote server set up a sftp-only non-root account with these contents of sshd_config:

```
Match User pavel
ForceCommand internal-sftp
# Don't add more lines below, they will be inside a Match block.
```

On local system install and configure sshfs. Use `-o reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=5,ServerAliveCountMax=3` like I describe [in another answer](https://serverfault.com/a/639735/9461). Optionally install and configure autofs, which will provide automatic mount/umount.

No ssh access: **check**.

Only reading/writing to remote sub-folder: **check**.

Preserve user, groups: **only in a very limited manner** (exactly like sftp command).

Preserve permissions: **check** (but google sftp umask)

Easy to configure (like sshfs): **check**.

It should be in standard Linux repositories: **check**.

It should reconnect if connection drops (or ip changes): **check**.

If you get it to work, you could also play with adding `ChrootDirectory /only/this/path` to sshd_config for increased security.

Comment: sounds like solution, I didn't know about ForceCommand internal-sftp. I need this to for off site backups, suppose it's needed by many

Comment: You can have multiple accounts under chroot.  I do this using a group called `sftponly` and a match block in sshd_config for that group.  Match can use User, Group or Net.  You can nearly duplicate rsync behavior in chroot using **[lftp](https://serverfault.com/questions/836103/replace-scp-with-sftp/836136#836136)** + sftp chroot.